# How to generate unusual but mathematically valid RSA keys?

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm using an RSA library that crashes at certain decrypt operations that contain invalid ciphertext. For security reasons, I don't have access to the RSA key or the ciphertext that are involved in crashes.

In my lab, I tried to submit multiple RSA keys and tweaked ciphertext values to force the crash. I tried with keys from 512 to 4096 bits, and I tweaked a valid ciphertext by changing each bit, prepending garbage, appending garbage, truncating at the tail or truncating at the head. In all cases, the library behaves correctly and reports "invalid ciphertext supplied" instead of crashing as it randomly happens on production.

My last resort is to try unusual RSA keys, for instance with unusual exponents. Do you know any library or tool that allows me to fully customize RSA key generation?

I can call it from C#, Java or C++ (Visual Studio), or it can also be a Windows command-line tool. Sample code or link to reference documentation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it's the keys fault? And even if, finding the crashing type of key won't help you if you don't know the used key for your data and can't change it. Get the author to correct it...

Comment: Have you checked that it's not an overflow by submitting too large values?

Comment: I would be careful implementing your own security functions for production use.  That's how exploits happen.

Comment: @deviantfan It can be the key fault, or the ciphertext fault. I just want to make sure the library works for every type of key. It could also be some memory or thread issue, but we hashed the ciphertext and found that certain ciphertexts always cause the crash, even after a fresh restart.

Comment: @deW1 Haven't tried that, will check and report.

Comment: @user3853544 Please read the question. I'm not implementing any security function.

Comment: Have you trapped the exception? Maybe hooking to AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException can help you to diagnose the error

Comment: There is very likely a different problem that is causing your application to crash.  You can't assume that it is an "unusual RSA key".

Answer (score 2):

The CoreFX RSA tests have a couple of [unusual keys defined](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/12a32bec60794664178886e6c1157677b883ded6/src/Common/tests/System/Security/Cryptography/AlgorithmImplementations/RSA/TestData.cs).

`DiminishedDPParameters` has a `DP` value which can be expressed with one less byte than usual (when P and Q are both half the width of N/D DP is usually the same size as P or Q).  (Generation technique: keep hitting up-enter with `openssl genrsa [keysize] | openssl rsa -text -noout` until one of the parameters was deficient)

`UnusualExponentParameters` uses `E=0x01B1` instead of `E=0x010001` (Generation technique: OpenSSL's [RSA_generate_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html) takes a value for E.  Just made one up, but stuck with a prime number for ease of the generator.)

One other thing that makes for an unusual E value is to be larger than 4 bytes (a limitiation of Windows CAPI / .NET `RSACryptoServiceProvider`).  There doesn't seem to be a test with one of those, so here's an inline version.  (Crypto disclaimer: This key was generated as an example, and has clearly been exposed to the Internet, don't use it for anything you want to be secret).

```
$ openssl rsa -in bigexponent.key -text -noout
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
    00:af:81:c1:cb:d8:20:3f:62:4a:53:9e:d6:60:81:
    75:37:23:93:a2:83:7d:48:90:e4:8a:19:de:d3:69:
    73:11:56:20:96:8d:6b:e0:d3:da:a3:8a:a7:77:be:
    02:ee:0b:6b:93:b7:24:e8:dc:c1:2b:63:2b:4f:a8:
    0b:bc:92:5b:ce:62:4f:4c:a7:cc:60:63:06:b3:94:
    03:e2:8c:93:2d:24:dd:54:6f:fe:4e:f6:a3:7f:10:
    77:0b:22:15:ea:8c:bb:5b:f4:27:e8:c4:d8:9b:79:
    eb:33:83:75:10:0c:5f:83:e5:5d:e9:b4:46:6d:df:
    be:ee:42:53:9a:ef:33:ef:18:7b:77:60:c3:b1:a1:
    b2:10:3c:2d:81:44:56:4a:0c:10:39:a0:9c:85:cf:
    6b:59:74:eb:51:6f:c8:d6:62:3c:94:ae:3a:5a:0b:
    b3:b4:c7:92:95:7d:43:23:91:56:6c:f3:e2:a5:2a:
    fb:0c:14:2b:9e:06:81:b8:97:26:71:af:2b:82:dd:
    39:0a:39:b9:39:cf:71:95:68:68:7e:49:90:a6:30:
    50:ca:77:68:dc:d6:b3:78:84:2f:18:fd:b1:f6:d9:
    ff:09:6b:af:7b:eb:98:dc:f9:30:d6:6f:cf:d5:03:
    f5:8d:41:bf:f4:62:12:e2:4e:3a:fc:45:ea:42:bd:
    88:47
publicExponent: 8589935681 (0x200000441)
privateExponent:
    64:af:9b:a5:26:24:83:da:92:b5:3f:13:43:9f:d0:
    ef:13:01:2f:87:9a:bc:03:cb:7c:06:f1:20:99:04:
    f3:52:c1:f2:23:51:9d:c4:8b:fa:ee:bb:51:1b:0d:
    95:5f:61:67:b5:0e:03:4f:ea:2a:bc:59:0b:4e:a9:
    fb:f0:c5:1f:9f:fe:a1:6f:79:27:ae:68:1c:bf:73:
    58:45:2b:ca:29:d5:87:05:e0:ca:a1:06:01:3b:09:
    a6:f5:f5:91:14:98:d2:c4:fd:69:15:58:54:88:e5:
    f3:ad:89:83:6c:93:c8:77:5a:fa:b4:d1:3c:20:14:
    26:6b:e8:ee:6b:8a:a6:6c:9e:94:2d:49:34:66:c8:
    e3:a3:70:f8:e6:37:8c:e9:5d:63:7e:03:67:36:70:
    be:4b:ca:ce:5f:cd:ad:d2:38:d9:f3:2c:a3:5d:e8:
    45:77:6a:c4:bf:36:11:88:12:32:8c:49:3f:91:c2:
    5a:9b:d4:26:72:d0:af:af:de:0a:f7:e6:19:07:8d:
    48:b4:85:ef:91:93:3d:dc:ff:b5:45:87:b8:f5:12:
    d2:23:c8:18:94:e9:17:84:98:2f:3c:5c:65:87:13:
    51:f4:65:5a:b0:23:c4:ad:99:b6:b0:3a:96:f9:04:
    6c:e1:24:a4:71:e8:28:f0:5f:8d:b3:bc:7c:cc:f2:
    d1
prime1:
    00:e4:3a:38:26:a9:72:04:ae:3c:d8:64:9a:84:db:
    4b:bf:07:25:c4:b0:8f:8c:43:84:05:57:a0:cd:04:
    e3:13:af:6d:04:60:dd:e6:9c:dc:50:8a:d0:43:d7:
    25:14:da:7a:66:bc:91:8c:d9:62:4f:48:56:44:b9:
    de:ea:b2:be:0e:11:29:56:d4:72:cf:0f:d5:1f:80:
    fd:33:87:2d:2d:cc:56:2a:05:88:b0:12:e8:c9:0c:
    e7:d2:54:b9:47:92:c6:e7:a0:2b:3c:ca:a1:50:e6:
    7a:64:37:7a:cc:49:47:9a:d5:eb:55:54:93:b2:10:
    0c:b0:41:09:56:f7:d7:3b:f5
prime2:
    00:c4:dd:2d:7a:dd:6c:a5:07:40:d3:97:3f:40:c4:
    de:bd:ba:b5:1f:7f:51:81:ab:ae:72:6c:32:59:6a:
    3e:dd:0a:ee:44:da:ad:dd:8a:9b:7a:86:4c:4f:fd:
    ae:00:c4:cb:1f:10:17:7b:a0:1c:04:66:f8:12:d5:
    22:61:0f:8c:45:43:f1:c3:ef:57:9f:a9:e1:3a:e8:
    da:1a:4a:8d:ae:30:78:61:d2:ce:ac:03:56:02:79:
    b6:1b:65:14:98:98:83:fe:86:c5:c7:42:0d:31:28:
    38:fc:2f:70:be:d5:9b:52:29:65:42:01:88:26:64:
    ce:fa:38:b4:8a:37:23:e9:cb
exponent1:
    09:ec:f1:51:f5:cd:d2:c9:e6:e5:26:82:36:4f:a5:
    b4:ed:09:4f:62:2e:40:31:bf:46:b8:51:35:8a:58:
    4d:cc:b5:32:8b:0b:d9:b6:35:89:18:3f:49:15:93:
    d2:a3:ac:ad:14:e0:aa:cd:a1:f1:81:b5:c7:d9:3c:
    57:ed:26:e6:2c:9f:c2:6a:f3:7e:4a:06:44:ec:e8:
    2a:7b:a8:ae:d8:8f:f1:d8:e9:c5:6c:c6:63:85:cd:
    b2:44:eb:3d:57:d1:7e:6a:d4:20:b1:9c:9e:2b:ee:
    18:19:2b:81:62:65:b7:4d:a5:5f:a3:82:5f:92:2d:
    9d:8e:83:5b:76:bf:30:71
exponent2:
    00:89:b3:3b:69:57:89:17:4b:88:36:8c:49:46:39:
    d4:d3:26:72:24:57:2a:40:b2:fe:61:91:03:84:22:
    8e:3d:bd:11:ee:d9:04:0c:d0:39:77:e9:e0:d7:fc:
    8b:fc:4b:f4:a9:32:83:52:9f:f1:d9:65:90:b1:8f:
    4e:ab:ef:03:03:79:4f:29:3e:88:dc:76:1b:3e:23:
    af:ec:b1:9f:29:f8:a4:d2:a9:05:8b:71:4c:f3:f4:
    d1:07:33:f1:3e:a7:2b:bf:1f:be:c8:d7:1e:10:6d:
    0c:e2:11:5f:3a:d2:de:02:03:25:c3:87:9a:09:1c:
    41:3c:d6:39:7f:83:b3:cb:89
coefficient:
    7c:57:ed:74:c9:17:6f:ba:76:c2:31:83:20:25:15:
    06:2c:66:4d:4d:49:ff:3e:03:70:47:a3:09:da:10:
    f1:59:0c:e0:1b:7a:1c:d1:a4:32:6d:c7:58:83:df:
    f9:31:10:ab:06:5a:ae:d1:40:c9:b9:81:76:a8:81:
    08:09:ad:ec:75:e8:67:64:a0:95:15:97:ef:46:7f:
    a8:fd:50:91:81:cd:2e:49:1e:43:be:41:08:4e:5b:
    e1:b5:62:ee:76:e9:f9:2c:9a:b1:e5:ae:ad:9d:29:
    1a:63:37:e4:de:85:bd:e6:7a:0d:72:b4:e5:5a:dc:
    f2:07:f7:a5:a5:22:5e:15
```